# If the lunar tides are stronger than solar tides, doesn't that imply the surface gravity of the moon is greater than the surface gravity of the sun?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

This is not a new argument but I wanted to see what sort of counter-arguments are produced here. According to Wikipedia, the Sun's surface gravity is 28.02 times earth surface gravity, and the moon's surface gravity is 0.1654 times earth surface gravity.

Assumption set 1:

The angular diameter or apparent diameter of an object is:

```
2*arcsin(diameter-actual/2/distance to object)
```

For the sun and moon, these are very nearly the same (during an eclipse, the sun and moon appear to be almost exactly the same size), so

```
diameter-sun/2/distance to sun = diameter-moon/2/distance to moon
```

or

```
distance to sun / distance to moon = diameter-sun / diameter-moon
```

Assumption set 2:

```
SurfaceGravitySun = GravitationalParameterSun/HalfSunsDiameterSquared

SurfaceGravityMoon = GravitationalParameterMoon/HalfMoonsDiameterSquared

SunsGravityForceAtEarth = GravitationalParameterSun/DistanceToSunSquared

MoonsGravityForceAtEarth = GravitationalParameterMoon/DistanceToMoonSquared
```

where the GravatationalParameter is the Gravitational Constant multiplied by the mass of the Sun or Moon.

So...

```
SurfaceGravitySun * HalfSunsDiameterSquared = DistanceToSunSquared * SunsGravityForceAtEarth
```

and

```
SurfaceGravityMoon * HalfMoonsDiameterSquared = DistanceToMoonSquared * MoonsGravityForceAtEarth
```

If we divide the equations we get equation 1:

```
SurfaceGravitySun * HalfSunsDiameterSquared / SurfaceGravityMoon / HalfMoonsDiameterSquared =
```

DistanceToSunSquared*SunsGravityForceAtEarth / DistanceToMoonSquared / MoonsGravityForceAtEarth

Going back to Assumption set 1,

```
DistanceToSun/DistanceToMoon = DiamenterSun/DiameterMoon
```

which we can easily make into equation 2:

```
HalfDistanceToSunSquared/HalfDistanceToMoonSquared = HalfSunsDiameterSquared/HalfMoonsDiameterSquared
```

So now substitution of equation 2 into 1 yields...

```
SurfaceGravitySun * HalfDistanceToSunSquared / SurfaceGravityMoon / HalfDistanceToMoonSquared = 
DistanceToSunSquared * SunsGravityForceAtEarth / DistanceToMoonSquared / MoonsGravityForceAtEarth
```

Removing and cancelling the Half's on the left side means the distance terms completely cancel, leaving equation 3:

```
SurfaceGravitySun / SurfaceGravityMoon = SunsGravityForceAtEarth / MoonsGravityForceAtEarth
```

Assumption set 3:

Lunar tides are stronger than solar tides, therefore SunsGravityForceAtEarth < MoonsGravityForce at earth.

Therefore

```
SurfaceGravityMoon > SurfaceGravitySun
```

Something's not right here, obviously. So what's wrong with the argument?

Comment: Tidal forces go like the *rate of change* of gravitational forces, which makes them vary with the *cube* of the distance rather than the square. That's why the Moon wins: it's much closer. [Previously](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149487/44126).

Comment: Well that's a head scratcher.

Comment: If it's not clear, we might hash it out over in [chat].

Comment: I read the other answer, I see the problem must be resolved in the tidal physics. Thank you