# Are there any effect of Sun to the tide?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, sun, solar-system, tidal-effect

The Earth is rotating for the Sun's gravitational field. Like a free falling object Earth should feel zero gravity to the Sun. So why there are effect of Sun to the tide?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111685/2451

Answer (score 1):

The moon also will feel tidal forces from the earth (we don't see this because there is no water on the moon!) even though the moon technically is falling toward the earth as the earth is falling toward the sun. Tidal forces are caused because of difference in how the forces are felt at different points across the orbiting object.

Even though the Sun is much further away from the Earth as the Moon is from earth, its gravitational force on the Earth is many times larger. Yet its tidal effect is smaller than that of the Moon. This is because tides are caused by the difference in the gravitational force across the body. The Earth's diameter is a very small fraction of the Sun-Earth distance so that the gravity differential across earth is relatively very small. The actual force differential across the Earth is about 0.035 times the sun's force, compared to about 0.07 difference across the Earth for the Moon's force.

The actual tidal influence due to the sun therefore, is about half that of the Moon.